# Reversing domain text in excel formula (split, reverse array, join)

Tags: excel

Say I have a field in excel with a domain name and I would like to reverse the order of the subdomains, domain and tld, for sorting purposes. For example:

"my.sub.domain.example.org" becomes "org.example.domain.sub.my"

How would you do that in excel?

Comment: In Excel O365 one could use: `=TEXTJOIN(".",,SORTBY(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+1),-1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would do it with worksheet functions, creating a function to do it for you is a lot easier.

If you open the VBA editor, insert a new module and paste the following function you can use it on your worksheet.

```
Public Function Reverse(ByVal Expression As String, ByVal Delimiter As String) As String
Dim Data() As String
Dim Result As String
Dim Index As Integer

    Result = ""
    Data = Split(Expression, Delimiter)
    Index = UBound(Data)

    Result = Data(Index)

    Do
        Index = Index - 1
        Result = Result & Delimiter & Data(Index)
    Loop While Index > 0

    Reverse = Result

End Function
```

Example

```
A1 ="my.example.site.tld"
A2 ="=Reverse(A1,".")"
A2=="tld.site.example.my"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use text to columns with a period delimiter. then you can splice them together using =concatenate(...) or & (concatenation operand) in the order and format that you desire.

(but the VBA answer NickSlash posted is nice, this is just in case you want non-VBA)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but but NickSlash's suggestion would work better in my case since I want to do this on imported data regularly. I know I didn't exactly specify this requirement in the description.